# Remove bundled APK from Selenium & Appium Test Project

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I have been trying to set-up a Java based test framework that uses Maven, TestNg, Selenium, Appium & Cucumber. I have managed to get everything to work but the last thing I would like to do is remove the dependency to include a pre-built APK as part of the test project.

The app I am testing is a react-native application that as part of its build process will publish an APK into an internal Maven repo (works great). I would like to update the test project to pull in the latest published version (as one build will trigger the other).

I can get the APK to be downloaded by adding something like this to my POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.XXX.XXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXX</artifactId>
    <version>(, 1.0]</version>
    <type>apk</type>
</dependency>
```

Is there a way to then have Appium make use of the downloaded APK e.g. through the app capability? Or some other way of getting this installed?